# Creating Azure AD user from Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-runbook

I'm trying to use an Azure Automation account + accompanying powershell runbook to automate the process of creating an Azure Active Directory user.

When I run the following command, I'm presented with the error, am I trying to achieve the impossible here or is there an easy fix to this problem:

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Surname'.
   at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.VerifyArgumentsProcessed(ParameterBindingException originalBindingException)
   at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParametersNoValidation(Collection`1 arguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

My runbook has the following script:

```
Param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $firstname,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $lastname,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $city,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $phone,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $pw,
    [string]$method,
    [string]$UAMI 
)
$displayname = $firstname + " " + $lastname
$upn = "$firstname.$lastname" + "@aguafriawindowslive.onmicrosoft.com"

#Secret Password
$secureStrPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pw -AsPlainText -Force

$automationAccount = "automationaccount01"

# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null

# Connect using a Managed Service Identity
try {
        $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
    }
catch{
        Write-Output "There is no system-assigned user identity. Aborting."; 
        exit
    }

# set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription `
    -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

if ($method -eq "SA")
    {
        Write-Output "Using system-assigned managed identity"
    }
elseif ($method -eq "UA")
    {
        Write-Output "Using user-assigned managed identity"

        # Connects using the Managed Service Identity of the named user-assigned managed identity
        $identity = Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
            -Name $UAMI -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

        # validates assignment only, not perms
        if ((Get-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
                -Name $automationAccount `
                -DefaultProfile $AzureContext).Identity.UserAssignedIdentities.Values.PrincipalId.Contains($identity.PrincipalId))
            {
                $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $identity.ClientId).context

                # set and store context
                $AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
            }
        else {
                Write-Output "Invalid or unassigned user-assigned managed identity"
                exit
            }
    }
else {
        Write-Output "Invalid method. Choose UA or SA."
        exit
     }


#Create User
New-AzADUser -DisplayName $displayname -UserPrincipalName $upn -Surname $lastname -City $city -Password $secureStrPassword -MailNickname $firstname -ForceChangePasswordNextLogin
```

Comment: What version of Az Powershell is your runbook using? The -Surname parameter only came in with 7.x of the Az Powershell module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azaduser?view=azps-6.6.0)

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood you're quite right. Thank you. I created a new runbook with v7 and was able to progress to a new error. 'Insufficient privileges'

Comment: At what step are you hitting that error? I didn't see anywhere in the script where you're connecting to AzureAD either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insufficient privileges error occurs when you have missed giving role required to do operation on the resources.Ensure that your runbook account has permissions to access any resources used in your script.

Try this:
Go to Azure portal --> Azure AD --> **roles and Administrator**-->**Directory Readers** role --> assign this role to the your runbook account name.

[image]

or

Try to add the application permissions > `Directory.Read.All` in  for the azure ad App of your automation run as account and also Directory.ReadWrite.All  if required   and grant admin consent to it.